# how does DFS work on nested arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, depth-first-search

Can someone please explain how does DFS work on nested arrays.
I'm referring to all wiki and stackover sources, but I dont quite understand how to do a recursive search on a an arry using DFS, consider this as my array:

```
array = ["abc","abc2","abc22"];
array[0] = ["test","test1","test2"];
array[0][0] = ["22","33","333"];
array[0][1] = ["we","we2","we3"];
array[0][1][2] = ["soon","soon2","soon3"];
array[1] = ["get"];
array[1][0] ="get2";
array[2] = ["set","set2","set3"];
array[2][0] = "ready";
array[2][1] = ["123","334"];
array[2][2] ="cry";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fmbw0eth/7/

how do we traverse through every element in the array and its child arrays and so on..
So I have this so far:

```
array.map(function(n,i){
  if (Array.isArray(n)) {
  n.map(function(n,i){
   // and keep checking for arrays and when reached at the bottom ,
   // somefunction(n);
})
}else {
someFucntion(n);
}

})
```

Is this the right approach for DFS, or is there a better recursive way to traverse the array?

Comment: You should really add the relevant code inside your question. You refer to code posted by someone asking a question. It is a bit strange that you ask us to explain their code... For one it is not a pure DFS algorithm...

Comment: Secondly, your array initialisation code is overwriting earlier values. This is not really how a nested array would normally be created.

Comment: sorry but I'm still figuring my out of the algorithms part, do you have a source you can direct me to if this is not how it works.? thx

Comment: Of course; there are plenty of them. Like [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode). The first version is true DFS. The difference with the second one (which is much like what you refer to) is explained in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DFS are used for graphs or trees. What you are working with is an array. If you want to visit all possible nested arrays and their indexes, you can use recursion to iterate through elements that are arrays.

```js
var array;
array = ["abc","abc2","abc22"];
array[0] = ["test","test1","test2"];
array[0][0] = ["22","33","333"];
array[0][1] = ["we","we2","we3"];
array[0][1][2] = ["soon","soon2","soon3"];
array[1] = ["get"];
array[1][0] ="get2";
array[2] = ["set","set2","set3"];
array[2][0] = "ready";
array[2][1] = ["123","334"];
array[2][2] ="cry";

function getAllNestedElements(arr) {
 var result = [];
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
     if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
         result = result.concat(getAllNestedElements(arr[i]));
        }
        else {
         result.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    //console.log(result);
    return result;
}

console.log(getAllNestedElements(array));
```